# Cumulative count over time on the 2nd purchase by a user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to be able to find the second time a user made a purchase. I'm currently using MIN(), in order to find the first date in the table. I'm unsure how I might be able to find anything other than the first and the last.

```
--First we create a table to find the date that the user first made a purchase

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FirstPurchase
SELECT UserId, MIN(DateCreated) AS FirstPurchase
INTO #FirstPurchase
FROM TrackedPurchase
GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY FirstPurchase

--We then create a table for the first time a user triggered an event

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FirstEvent
SELECT DistinctId, MIN(DateCreated) AS FirstEvent
INTO #FirstEvent
FROM MixPanelEvent
WHERE Event = 'dis_offer' OR Event = 'offer'
GROUP BY DistinctId
ORDER BY FirstEvent

--We then create a table to do a cumulative count for the day by day

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CumulativeCountPurchasesByTime
SELECT CAST(FirstPurchase AS DATE) as Date, COUNT(UserId) as UserCount, SUM(COUNT(UserId)) OVER (ORDER BY CAST(FirstPurchase AS DATE)) as CumulativeCount
INTO #CumulativeCountPurchasesByTime
FROM #FirstPurchase
GROUP BY CAST(FirstPurchase AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(FirstPurchase AS DATE);

--We then create a table to do a cumulative count for the day by day of uses

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CumulativeCountUsesByTime
SELECT CAST(FirstUse AS DATE) as Date, COUNT(DistinctId) as UserCount, SUM(COUNT(DistinctId)) OVER (ORDER BY CAST(FirstUse AS DATE)) as CumulativeCount
INTO #CumulativeCountUsesByTime
FROM #FirstUse
GROUP BY CAST(FirstUse AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(FirstUse AS DATE);

-- We then prepare the data for export

SELECT a.Date, a.UserCount AS UsesCount, a.CumulativeCount AS CumulativeUses, b.UserCount AS PurchaseCount, b.CumulativeCount AS CumulativePurchases
FROM #CumulativeCountUsesByTime a
LEFT JOIN #CumulativeCountPurchasesByTime b
ON a.Date = b.Date
ORDER BY a.Date
```

I'd like to be able to define the Nth time and just alter the code to see how many users have completed purchases over time at a cumulative level.

Comment: The `INSERT...INTO` statements are *nice* but if operates off the statement `FROM TrackedPurchase`, which we don't have access to; making the whole thing somewhat useless.

Comment: use the row_number() with partition by function to determine how many time a single user made a puchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine was able to resolve this using the rank function.

EDIT: the data just needs tidying up for the purpose of my analysis.

```
-- User level summary
drop table if exists #userlevel
select userid
,      DateCreated
,      RANK() OVER(Partition by userid order by userid ASC, DateCreated ASC) as 'RewardNo'
into #userlevel
from dbo.TrackedReward
select * from #userlevel
order by userid, DateCreated
-- Summary by date and no. rewards
select convert(date,datecreated) as rewarddate
,      RewardNo
,      count(*) as users
from #userlevel
group by convert(date,datecreated)
,      RewardNo
order by convert(date,datecreated)
,      RewardNo
```

Answer (score 0):

To select second purchase item you can select top2 purchase items ordered by date ascending and the select maximum of these two date.e.g.:

```
SELECT * from table 
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(t1.Date) FROM (SELECT top 2 * FROM table WHERE UserId=1 ORDER BY date asc ) AS t1)
```

Using this way you also can find third - by selecting top 3 and then Max of them etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data (we can't use the above, as we're missing the object `TrackedPurchase`) and expected result this is a complete guess, however, I suspect you could make use of a CTE as `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
DECLARE @N int = 2;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CustomerName,
           CustomerOrder,
           CustomerOrderDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY CustomerOrderDate) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT CustomerName,
       CustomerOrder,
       CustomerOrderDate
FROM CTE C
WHERE RN = @N;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT DateCreated,
       SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as first_on_day,
       SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as second_on_day,
       SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) OVER (ORDER BY DateCreated) as first_thru_day,
       SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) OVER (ORDER BY DateCreated) as second_true_day,
FROM (SELECT mpe.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DistinctId ORDER BY DateCreated) as seqnum  
      FROM MixPanelEvent mpe
      WHERE Event IN ('dis_offer', 'offer')
     ) mpe
GROUP BY DateCreated
ORDER BY DateCreated;
```